# getIdentifier doesn't give the correct id

Tags: java, android, view

So I have more imageView looking like this:

> imageView1
>
> ...
>
> imageView8

```
int defendPosition = defend(); // This is random generated number from 1-8;
String imageID = "imageView" + defendPosition;
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(imageID, "id", getPackageName());
Log.i("resID", " "+ resID); // it logs value is 0
secondMove = findViewById(resID);
secondMove.setTranslationY(-1500); // When I try to run this, it says null refference;
```

I need to get the correct id

Comment: `it logs value is 0` – That would mean that you're passing an invalid name `String`, one for which there isn't an `R.id` in your app.

Comment: Post your xml file. Also have you added you inflated your xml correctly?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
int resID=this.getResources().getIdentifier(imageID,"id",getActivity().getPackageName())
```